# How to layout the dashboard sections vertically with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In the `dashboards.rb` file generated by [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) 0.3.4, I added three sections consisting on wide tables with several columns. However ActiveAdmin displays each section next to the other, creating an unnecessary horizontal scrollbar.

How can I change this to a vertical layout?

**dashboards.rb:**

```
ActiveAdmin::Dashboards.build do
  section "Inactive users" do
    table do
      ...
    end
  end

  section "Deleted posts" do
    table do
      ...
    end
  end

  section "Latest comments" do
    table do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**What I get:**

[image: dashboard preview]

I already tried using a div as the container for each table with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed this with some CSS, in a new stylesheet:

**active_admin_ex.css:**

```
table.dashboard > tbody > tr > td {
  display:block;
}
```

Then, in **config/initializers/active_admin.rb**, I added:

```
config.register_stylesheet 'active_admin_ex.css'
```

And this fixed the display problem.

Answer (score 12):

This answer for active_admin >= 0.5.1

Dashboard is structured in columns and panels
Columns are... well, columns, which define the horizontal layout.
Panels are like sections that stack verticaly.

A 2 column, 3 sections en each column, would be defined by:

```
columns do
  column do
    panel "top on column 1"
      # some code
    end
    panel "second on column 1"
      # some code
    end
    panel "last on column 1"
      # some code
    end
  end
  column do
    panel "top on column 2"
      # some code
    end
    panel "second on column 2"
      # some code
    end
    panel "last on column 2"
      # some code
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

more flexible, you can override the render_sections of the Dashboard class to use colspan:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    module Pages
      class Dashboard < Base

        protected

        def render_sections(sections)
          cloned_sections = sections.clone
          table :class => "dashboard" do

            while !cloned_sections.empty?
              current_cols_number = 0
              tr do
                while current_cols_number < 12 && !cloned_sections.empty?
                  s       = cloned_sections.shift
                  colspan = s.options[:colspan].nil? ? 4 : s.options[:colspan]
                  td colspan: colspan do
                    render_section(s)
                  end
                  current_cols_number += colspan
                end
              end
            end

          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

you can add this code at the beginning of you `app/admin/dashboard.rb` file and then add the `:colspan` option when declaring a section:

```
  section "All time summary" , colspan: 6 , priority: 2  do
    div do
      render 'all_time_summary'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Amazing solution , the best approach i think. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CSS to prevent that

```
div :class => 'some class name' do

end
```

style that class

Comment: Actually, each section is inside a table so I needed more CSS than expected (see my answer). Thanks anyway for the CSS idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
columns do
      column do
        panel "Recent Created Restaurant" do
          table_for Restaurant.order('id desc').limit(5).each do |restaurant|
            column (:id) {|restaurant| link_to(restaurant.id, admin_restaurant_path(restaurant)) }
            column :name
            column :phone              
            column :updated_at
          end # table
        end # panel
      end # column


  column do
    panel "Recent Created Menu" do
      table_for Menu.order('id desc').limit(5).each do |menu|
        column (:id) {|menu| link_to(menu.id, admin_menu_path(menu)) }
        column :name
        column "Restaurant Name" do |menu|
          menu.restaurant.name
        end
        column :updated_at
      end # table
    end # panel
  end # column

  column do
    panel "Recent Created Order" do
      table_for Order.order('id desc').limit(5).each do |order|
        column (:id) {|order| link_to(order.id, admin_order_path(order)) }
        column :table
        column :status
        column "Item Name" do |order|
          order.item_orders.id
        end
        column :updated_at
      end # table
    end # panel
  end # column




end # columns
```

Comment: Please can you expand on your code, what is it doing and why would it work for the user? General code dumps without context and often frowned upon